# How to embed tableau into asp.net core blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, tableau-api, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to embed tableau object into razor page in **blazor** application but its not working it shows blank page and it will not log any error in browser console.

Below is the razor page.

**Tableau.razor**

```cs
    @page "/tableau"

    <h3>Tableau Example</h3>

    <body>
        <div class='tableauPlaceholder' style='width: 1700px; height: 950px;'>
        <object class='tableauViz' width='1700' height='950' style='display:none;'>
            <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Ftableau.xxxxxx.com%2F' /> 
            <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> 
            <param name='site_root' value='&#47;t&#47;ITRD' />
            <param name='name' value='AgileDEStrainingStatus&#47;Agilemind-setTrainings' />
            <param name='tabs' value='yes' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
            <param name='showAppBanner' value='false' />
            <param name='filter' value='iframeSizedToWindow=true' /></object></div>
    </body>


    @code {

    }
```

**_host.cshtml**

```cs
    @page "/"
    @namespace BlazorApplication.Pages
    @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>BlazorApplication</title>
        <base href="~/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <app>
            @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
        </app>

        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://tableau.xxxxxx.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js'></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: For how to invoke js,you could refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: @Rena I have already read the doc,but I dint get the idea since we are not manually calling javascript function.

Comment: I assume you see the page and the `div` and `object` tags are rendered? Did you use devtools to check for any 404 or 500 errors in the network list?

Comment: @Quango There was not errors in console or networking list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't replicate your exact sample as the URL for your data is obviously private, but I created a Tableau sample at https://github.com/conficient/TableauSample which uses the [basic example from the Tableau website](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_basic_embed.htm)

I used Server-side Blazor as per your example and was able to load the sample. What I think you're missing in your code is that there is no initiation of the Tableau library? In the Tableau sample they invoke the setup function:

```
<body onload="initViz();">
```

You can't do this in Blazor since embedded JS isn't permitted but you can use [JavaScript interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#javascript-interop)

I created a basic [interop file](https://github.com/conficient/TableauSample/blob/master/TableauSample/wwwroot/tableauInterop.js) to do this:

```
window.initViz = function (containerDiv, url) {
    // containerDiv: element to update - use @ref in Blazor to get this
    console.log("initViz called for " + url);

    var options = {
        hideTabs: true,
        onFirstInteractive: function () {
            console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
        }
    };
    console.log("initViz calling .Viz()");
    var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
}
```

I also changed the sample by passing an `ElementReference` rather than an `id` - if you're going to build a component in future this is good practice since you don't need to name the elements and can have multiple instances on a page.

I then amended the `Index.razor` page to invoke the `initViz` function in `OnAfterRenderAsync`.

[image: Demo]

Comment: I got it.Thank you very much.